# HTML XPath - How to select a node based on children's value per index?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

Given the following example HTML code:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div>Value 1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div>Value A</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div>Value 1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Value B</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div>Value A</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div>Value 1</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to write a xpath expression to select the (tr) element which has "Value 1" in the div of the first column and "Value 2" in the div of the second
column? In this example, I would want only the first row.

If I retrieve all rows which have descendents with "Value 1" I will get all 3 rows.

If I retrieve all rows which have descendents with "Value 1" and "Value A" I will get rows 1 and 3.

It's not only the value that matters, but also the order. Also, in my real case there are several columns and the ones I need to check may not be side by side. (Could be that I need to check columns 4 7 and 9, for example)

I think I'm looking for something like this, but its not working for me (odd formatting is for readability sake, but I believe its still valid):

```
//table//tr
[
(.//div[position()=1 and text()='Value 1']) 
and 
(.//div[position()=2 and text()='Value A'])
]
```

I've also tried [1] and [2] instead of position() to no avail. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple

```
//tr[normalize-space(td[1]/div) = 'Value 1' and normalize-space(td[2]/div) = 'Value A']
```

Demo - http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/e3d5b9bf-79d5-4e81-a336-daba38d430fe

Comment: @rink I'm guessing you had some carriage returns / other whitespace around the div text which is why the other answer didn't work. `normalize-space` is a handy function to keep around

Answer (score 0):

Your expression works for me, although I would write it like this:

```
//table/tr[td[1]/div = 'Value 1' and td[2]/div = 'Value A']
```

Comment: Hm. Thanks for your suggestion but neither my method nor your proposed method is working for me on the above example. They both are valid syntax-wise, but return no results.