# xpath to return xml nodes where attribute at certain index has value

Tags: xml, xpath

Here is a section of the xml.

```
<row>
  <boolean>true</boolean>
  <integer>1476589279770</integer>
  <integer>1475964900000</integer>
  <string nil="true"/>
  <integer>24</integer>
  <string>GYMC Sprint 1</string>
  <integer>5</integer>
  <integer nil="true"/>
  <boolean>true</boolean>
  <integer>1474755356654</integer>
</row>
<row>
  <boolean>false</boolean>
  <integer nil="true"/>
  <integer>1479136680000</integer>
  <string nil="true"/>
  <integer>47</integer>
  <string>TJI Sprint 1</string>
  <integer>24</integer>
  <integer nil="true"/>
  <boolean>true</boolean>
  <integer>1477923500196</integer>
</row>
<row>
  <boolean>false</boolean>
  <integer nil="true"/>
  <integer nil="true"/>
  <string nil="true"/>
  <integer>48</integer>
  <string>TJI Sprint 2</string>
  <integer>24</integer>
  <integer nil="true"/>
  <boolean>false</boolean>
  <integer nil="true"/>
</row>
```

Here is my xpath so far: This returns the previous data.

```
//data[@tableName='AO_60DB71_SPRINT']/row[integer='24']
```

My difficulty is that the nodes here have the same name happening more than once. I'm a little new xpath and xml so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which element you want to get exactly?

Comment: I want to return all <row>s that have the 4th integer array with the value I place in this case 24. As you can see from the example the first <row> node is incorrect b/c it's 3rd integer node is 24.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

I've now solved it. Due to [HTML XPath - How to select a node based on children's value per index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825619/html-xpath-how-to-select-a-node-based-on-childrens-value-per-index) I was able to understand how to do this. Here is the solution:

```
//data[@tableName='AO_60DB71_SPRINT']/row[normalize-space(integer[4])='24']
```